# Code generation for Azure Tables - ala ORM

Tags: orm, azure, azure-table-storage

I'd like to take several simple relational databases and switch them to use Azure Table Storage rather than simply drop them into SQLAzure.  I always use ORM generated code to access my database (in this case LLBLgenpro).  Is there any tooling that would review my relational database and generate ORM'ish code that works with Azure Table Storage for a persistance layer?

Comment: Like Igorek says, azure storage tables are not relational. I personally would not do this. May I ask why you want to? Is it because of cost?

Comment: I want to keep away from custom coding a DAL, so having something akin to an ORM would let me do an adapter based approach storing data in either a database or azure tables (or whatever, say, BigTable)

Answer (score 1):

There is not.  You can use Entity-Framework EDMX and modify the t4 (tt) files to build you ATS-compatible objects.  The effort may not be as beneficial however, since you cannot map any relationships or complex objects within your entities.

Comment: Using EF and T4 may a good starting point.   I'm not very concerned with string relationships, as weak ones are fine in my model.

Comment: Then T4 with modifications to inherit from base object/or interface that supports PartitionKey/RowKey/Timestamp will do just fine.  I've done this for a client.  We couldn't map all entities out, but majority of entities were not to hard to map out and we used partial classes to augment the non-generatable logic